# Ruby Process.kill can't kill system() in ruby child

Tags: ruby, process, kill-process, sigkill

In a ruby process I fork off a child with a system call in it.

I want to be able to kill the child and have that propagate to the system call, but the system call keeps running:

```
unless pid=fork
  system("echo start ; sleep 1 ; echo 1 ; sleep 1 ; echo 2 ; sleep 1 ; echo 3")
  exit
end
puts "Child: #{pid}"

sleep 2

Process.kill('-KILL',-pid)
```

How can I propagate the kill from ruby to it's forked system call?

Comment: I have a similar issue, did you find a solution to this eventually?

Comment: To which problem?  Using exec() solves the main problem.

Comment: Not for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41064139/terminating-a-ruby-fork-does-not-terminate-the-underlying-process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, `system` blocks. Use `exec` instead:
http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-exec

```
  unless pid=fork
    puts pid
    exec("echo start ; sleep 1 ; echo 1 ; sleep 1 ; echo 2 ; sleep 1 ; echo 3")
    exit
  end
  puts "Child: #{pid}"

  sleep 1

  Process.kill('KILL',pid)
  puts 'killed'
```

Comment: Actually, this doesn't quite answer the question.

If I have a ruby script that has a 'system' call with, for example, a sleep in it, then I can kill it with ctrl-c (UNIX).  But I can't kill the system call by sending the KILL signal to the ruby script.  Is that because the ctrl-c goes to the child/system() and it is sent up from the child?

Comment: Hmm, I don't know why Process.kill isn't terminating the child process, sorry. I checked, now, that ctrl-C does indeed terminate both processes while using `system`. You can un-accept my answer if you like.

Comment: Actually, I'll just leave it accepted since it's helped me figure out what the real question is - why ctrl-c acts different than Process.kill

I'm guessing that the ctrl-c is sent to the child instead of being propagated by the parent.