# Terminating a ruby fork does not terminate the underlying process

Tags: ruby

I am debugging a piece of code that looks like this:

```
    pid = fork do
      STDERR.reopen("/dev/null")
      STDOUT.reopen("/dev/null")
      exec('some bash command that runs in the foreground')
    end

    at_exit do
      Process.kill("TERM", pid)
      Process.wait pid
    end
```

The problem is the `Process.kill` will kill the fork but not the process that was started with exec.

How do I kill the fork and the exec process?

Comment: The forked process is the same as the `exec`ed process (they have the same pid), you can’t kill only one of them. Does your bash command start some other process?

Comment: Yes in my case the bash command starts `solr` in foreground

Comment: Try changing the exec command to something like a sleep, it's possible your bash command is ignoring some signals.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a TERM signal to a process that perhaps is blocking the TERM.  If you replace this with something simple like a 'sleep' you will see that it can be terminated.